# CLion 2022 no matching 'operator new' C++

Tags: c++, clion, clangd

I am getting this error from Clangd on std functions since I upgraded to CLion 2022.1.1:

> `In template: no matching 'operator new' function for non-allocating placement new expression; include <new>`

This error is displayed on std functions such as `push_back`, `make_shared`, `insert`, etc.

It seems to be a problem with **Clangd v15.0.0** because when I downgraded to CLion 2021 which uses Clangd v14 the error disappears. I tried adding the `,--target=riscv32` flag like mentioned [here](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360008390520-Clangd-error-on-placement-new-operator) but it didn't work.

Any ideas on how to fix this (without adding `include <new>` in every file of the project)?

Comment: Can you show us an example source file that produces this error?

Comment: I changed my question to answer your comments. @Chris this error is happening in literally every c++ file where I use std functions

Comment: What happens when you side-step CLion and compile from the command line?

Comment: I am using Emscripten to compile so the everything is still compiling just fine. I just get those annoying errors in every c++ files in CLion

Comment: Seems that clangd isn't recognizing the headers as system headers. It shouldn't show diagnostics for them. Did you specify any include directories to the system headers manually somewhere? In any case, I suggest you give a step-by-step for how you set up the project to cause this problem, so that others can reproduce it.

Comment: The issue seems to not happen in **CLion version** `2021.3.4`, I would use that until they patch it.

Comment: I met an same error when using `std::vector<unsigned long long> remv(100);`. So, have you found a solution now?